# SQL Azure simple update fails (or takes many minutes) not due to blocking

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have a table PropertyDefinition with 900 rows. A very simple update statement fails (or sometimes succeeds after 5 minutes). We checked for blocking SPIDs and there weren't any. We are in SQL Azure on Business Critical tier with 8 vcores.

Full disclosure: There are 250,000 tables that reference PropertyDefinition. Why on Earth? There are 700 users and each of them deals with 100 or so types of entity, and each of those has 4 or 5 tables. So for example, we use 'vince.EmailMessageValueBit' to store bit flags related to Vince's email messages. Aside from this current issue (which relates to the tiny PropertyDefinition table), the system has been performing well.

Here is the approximate update statement:

UPDATE i
SET Foo = i.Foo
FROM PropertyDefinition i
WHERE i.Id = 1;

Here is the PropertyDefinition table (no Foo column; the above was to give the idea):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDefinition](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Alias] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [ConcordanceRoleId] [int] NULL,
    [DontIndex] [bit] NULL,
    [EntityDefinitionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IncludeInSearch] [bit] NULL,
    [InheritsFromUri] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [IsCaseSensitive] [bit] NULL,
    [IsNullable] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MaxLength] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [PropertyAggregationTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [PropertyDataTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyValidationRuleId] [int] NULL,
    [RefdEntityUri] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [SensitiveInfoTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [TextifyAsOrdinal] [int] NULL,
    [TextifyPostText] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [TextifyPreText] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [UniquenessOrdinal] [int] NULL,
    [Uri] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [AggregationGroup] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [ConcordableEntityTypeUriForMd5] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [IsSourceTimestamp] [bit] NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NULL,
    [DontPush] [bit] NULL,
    [RedactableVia] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [AllowRedactedHintText] [bit] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Uri] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDefinition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ConcordanceRoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ConcordanceRole] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDefinition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([EntityDefinitionId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[EntityDefinition] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDefinition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PropertyAggregationTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PropertyAggregationType] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDefinition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PropertyDataTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PropertyDataType] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDefinition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PropertyValidationRuleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PropertyValidationRule] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyDefinition]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([SensitiveInfoTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SensitiveInfoType] ([Id])
GO
```

Here is an example of one of those 250,000 tables referencing it:

```
CREATE TABLE [myschemaname].[MyEntityValueBit](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [GraphedEntityRootId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [PropertyDefinitionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [bit] MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [GraphedEntityRootId] ASC,
    [PropertyDefinitionId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [myschemaname].[MyEntityValueBit]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([GraphedEntityRootId])
REFERENCES [myschemaname].[MyEntityRoot] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [myschemaname].[MyEntityValueBit]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PropertyDefinitionId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PropertyDefinition] ([Id])
GO
```

No blocks identified when running the SQL from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/understand-resolve-blocking), i.e.
WITH cteBL (session_id, blocking_these) AS ...

Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the actual execution plan for a successful run to your post. Are you able to download and run [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) (I'm not sure if it's supported on Azure SQL Database)?...it would tell you what your `UPDATE` statement is waiting on.

Comment: Yes. It was not waiting on anyone. Our latest suspicion btw is that the issue is all the foreign keys referencing this table (even though there's no delete of PropertyDefinition).

Comment: Waiting doesn't have to be from blocking / locking, it can also be from resource contention such as Memory, CPU, or I/O, or from a multitude of other things. I'd recommend trying to use `sp_WhoIsActive` to gather additional information while your `UPDATE` query is running. And again, without the [actual execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) of the completed query, there's not much we can really advise on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in fact all those foreign key references to the main table, PropertyDefinition. Even though it was an UPDATE to PropertyDefinition, not a DELETE, evidently they get looked at. Removing the FKs resolved the issue.